What is the proper Q&A community for this particular topic: allergies and robot vacuum cleaners
I want to find the proper community to ask about a technical specification detail regarding robot vacuum cleaners, important for allergic people: are their filters as good as the HEPA filters of traditional vacuum cleaners?
Which is the best community for this type of question? I haven't been lucky asking it in 'robotics', 'pets', or 'parenting' (I thought of those three because it's about robot vacuum cleaners; a certain amount of allergic dust comes from pets and I have a dog; my child and I are both allergic).

You could try Medical Sciences. See for example this search for HEPA.

Thank you so much @Franck Dernoncourt. For some reason I didn't notice that community before, and it seems the most appropiate to place my question.

FYI: the question from OP posted on medical sciences was closed as off-topic. So it seems that this is not the correct answer.

@Lino I disagree with the closure. Correct answer imho but mods there tend to close most questions. That partly explains https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1420/43

@FranckDernoncourt Of course you do; you disagree with every closure that ever happens. Please go read What topics can I ask about here and tell me what category you think that question falls under. Why on earth would medical professionals know anything about robot vacuum cleaners and the filters they use? It's absurd to think they would.

@CareyGregory It falls under "disease prevention".

@FranckDernoncourt No it doesn't. I repeat: Why on earth would medical professionals know anything about robot vacuum cleaners and the filters they use? The question required knowledge of robot vacuum cleaners and the materials they use, not how to prevent disease.

@CareyGregory "How different are generic so-called high efficiency filters from true HEPA filters?" and "I, being allergic, should be concerned about tiny particles getting expelled back to the ambient when the filters are not HEPA?" are clearly about disease prevention.
